# Linux Kernel Module: dynamically loading code at runtime

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

Is there a way to dynamically load compiled c-code in a linux-kernel-module at run-time?
I am looking for something like `dlopen` from `libdl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Move the code into another modules and then create a dependency to that other module in yours.

Comment: Thanks. But I meant without to create a new module, because if it is possible i wouldn't start more than one module. Regards

Comment: Why is it important to start only a single module?